# Creating many-to-many relationship code first

Tags: c#, migration, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship in C# using the code first approach. In the real world, a product can have many categories and a category can have many products. So this is what I've come up with:

Product.cs:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Category.cs:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category(CategoryEnum @enum)
    {
        Id = (int)@enum;
        Name = @enum.ToString();
    }

    public Category() { }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }


    public static implicit operator Category(CategoryEnum @enum) => new Category(@enum);

    public static implicit operator CategoryEnum(Category category) => (CategoryEnum)category.Id;

}
```

The `Category` maps to an `Enum` which looks like:

```
public enum CategoryEnum
{
    Electronics = 1,
    Gardening = 2
}
```

Finally, the `DbContext` looks like so:

```
public class ProductDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entities.Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entities.Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public ProductDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProductDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

When running migrations I get this result:

[image]

It's called name the columns like `CategoriesId` and `ProductsId` is there a way to change the name of these columns?

Comment: Change to what?

Comment: For example ```CategoryId``` and ```ProductId``` @CaiusJard

Comment: @CaiusJard Doesn't work, says ```The [ForeignKey] attribute cannot be specified on the skip navigation 'CategoryId'.'ProductId'. Configure the foreign key properties in 'OnModelCreating' instead```

Comment: What flavour/version of EF is this?

Comment: @CaiusJard EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder
            .Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Categories)
            .WithMany(p => p.Products)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>("ProductCategory",
              right => right.HasOne<Category>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("CategoryId")
                .HasConstraintName("FK_ProductCategory_CategoryId__Category_Id")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),
              left => left.HasOne<Product>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("ProductId")
                .HasConstraintName("FK_ProductCategory_ProductId__Product_Id")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
          );
    }
```

It works:

[image]

Comment: What on earth.. it can't be that hard to rename the columns generated.. right?

Comment: You can also create the middle man entity yourself I guess. It's only the top bit of code you need. End of the day, it's an auto generated table for something you never see in code side - do you really even care what the names are?  :)

Comment: I didn't quite understand why it's hard though; you just copy the code I wrote and paste it into your project. If you need to do it again with different columns, it's a copy/paste/replace exercise..